# Message Box Crashes after 10 seconds in Windows Phone 7 App

Tags: windows-phone-8

This is a problem i am experiencing in WP 7 app dev. Actually I want to detect the presence of network while the application launches 
 I use this code

```
bool isNetwork=NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
if(!isnetwork) 
{    
    MessageBox.Show("No Network Available","App Name",MessageBoxButton.OkCancel); 
}
```

The following code i am writing in the **Constructor()** of the class , I just want to know two things

1. Where should I write the code so that when the application opens, the message box is displayed and until the user selects "yes" or "No" the messagebox remains intact.
2. I want to exit the application when the user presses the "NO " button on the MessageBox

   I was confused, should i use the **application_launching()** event or Should I code in **OnNavigatedTo()** ?

Proper code is required ! Thanks :-)

Comment: This happened to me when opening a messagebox in the OnBackKeyPress handler. I fixed by immediately canceling the back key press and opening the messagebox on another thread. I navigate away manually after the user presses "OK".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your MessageBox in Constructor on OnNavigatedTo events, you will face the same issue. You have to handle it wisely in the page's `Loaded` event handler.

Programmatically there is no preffered way to exit the app. Instead of deciding to exit the app, I suggest you show some static content and a "No network available, try later" text on the page.

Comment: what If I want to Code the OnNavigatedTo() event for the App?

Comment: You can code that event.. but it is not wise to place the `messageBox` in that handler